# TextBox current line not visible when embedded in a scroll viewer

Tags: c#, textbox, silverlight-5.0

I have a `TextBox` inside a `ChildWindow` which I use for text input. I could not get the text box to scroll when the text does not fit inside so I wrapped it inside a `ScrollViewer`

```
    <ScrollViewer Height="200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox Name="TaskDescription" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

When the text box is full, it scrolls and this is expected. However, I do not see the current edited line.
[image]

I read articles on making the `ScrollViewer` automatically scroll but that will make my `TextBox` scroll to the end which won't allow editing text somewhere in the middle as it will jump to the end as soon as a key is typed.

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue, however, you should be able to add this `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` to your TextBox and remove the ScrollViewer all together.

Comment: @Nate I already tried that but it did not work :( the scroll bar does not appear

Comment: what if you change to Visible instead of Auto?

Comment: @Nate Tried that and it works but that's not the problem. I need a scroll bar for the usre to easily go up in the text, that scroll bar does however not automatically follow and stays on at the top at all times (unless I manually scroll down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ScrollViewer is trying to accommodate the size of the textbox, which is increasing in size. The better alternative to not use the scrollviewer and to let the textbox naturally place the scrollbars when needed. Nothing should need to be done so the textbox.

Comment: I can't get the `TextBox` to show the scroll bars even when the text does not fit.